# How to make Confusion-Matrix out of tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-classification

i want to print a confusion matrix.
My folder structure of the test images are:
Folder1/
folderA
folderB
folderC

My Code is:

```
img_height = 666
img_width = 888
data_dir = pathlib.Path('./Folder1/')

test_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  color_mode="grayscale",
  seed=123,
  label_mode='categorical',
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=1)


model = keras.models.load_model('./ThesisModel1.h5')
predictions = model.predict(test_ds)
print(predictions)
```

My problem is, i dont exactly understand, how i can get the true labels
out of the test_ds for the confusionmatrix.

```
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

The output of my predictions are something like:
[[9.7657585e-01 1.0853049e-08 2.3424132e-02 1.6444430e-08]
 [5.5932364e-10 9.7489715e-01 1.6656710e-09 2.5102831e-02]
 [1.0376019e-07 9.3018705e-01 1.3556164e-06 6.9811486e-02]
 [7.6754656e-09 8.5182555e-10 9.9994183e-01 5.8224105e-05]]
```